# Why Ubuntu is the most popular Linux distro in the world?

Tags: gnome

There are many Linux distros in the world. Why Ubuntu is the most popular one among them?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is so popular mostly because of historical reasons.

When other GNU/Linux operating systems were quite hard to set up (during early 2000s), Ubuntu appeared as an operating system with convenient default settings.

It was relatively easier to install than most other GNU/Linux OS. It was relatively easier to install software and drivers in Ubuntu.

That's why it initially got so popular. Nowadays, the difference (in terms of convenience) between Ubuntu and some other GNU/Linux operating systems (say, Linux Mint or Pop OS (both are based on Ubuntu)) is not that much.
However, Ubuntu remains so popular because in most cases it just works, and existing users continue to advise novice GNU/Linux users to use Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you elaborate some advantages of Ubuntu over other Linux distros?

Comment: One factor is the forums and level of support you can get from those forums, both on here and at https://ubuntuforums.org/

Comment: @li_jessen Having learned the joke yesterday: "Linux is a no-cost operating system if you don't value your time.", I would assume, that choosing Ubuntu, you will have to sacrifice a smaller amount of time, compared to the others, to get to the point where the computer exists for you, and not you for the computer.